# Spark Java Map function is getting executed twice

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have above code as Spark driver, when I execute my program it works properly saving required data as Parquet file.

```
String indexFile = "index.txt";
JavaRDD<String> indexData = sc.textFile(indexFile).cache();
JavaRDD<String> jsonStringRDD = indexData.map(new Function<String, String>() {
  @Override
  public String call(String patientId) throws Exception {
   return "json array as string"
  }   
}); 

//1. Read json string array into a Dataframe (execution 1)
DataFrame dataSchemaDF = sqlContext.read().json(jsonStringRDD );
//2. Save dataframe as parquet file (execution 2)
dataSchemaDF.write().parquet("md.parquet");
```

But I observed my mapper function on RDD `indexData` is getting executed twice.
first, when I read `jsonStringRdd` as `DataFrame` using `SQLContext`
Second, when I write the  `dataSchemaDF` to the parquet file

Can you guide me on this, how to avoid this repeated execution? Is there any other better way of converting JSON string into a Dataframe?

Comment: Where are you seeing two maps? RDD's are lazily evaluated. The `map` operation is a transformation, not an action, so the assignment of `jsonStringRDD` shouldn't be ran immediately. Maybe the execution paths for reading the Dataframe and writing out to parquet both require collection of the RDD.

Comment: I have logging statements in my mapper function, I see them twice in the log.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that the reason is a lack of schema for JSON reader. When you execute:

```
sqlContext.read().json(jsonStringRDD);
```

Spark has to infer schema for a newly created `DataFrame`. To do that it has scan input RDD and this step is performed eagerly

If you want to avoid it you have to create a `StructType` which describes the shape of the JSON documents:

```
StructType schema;
...
```

and use it when you create `DataFrame`:

```
DataFrame dataSchemaDF = sqlContext.read().schema(schema).json(jsonStringRDD);
```